# How to display Content in Modal in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to show `data` details in Modals one after another

such that it should display first object details and on click of next it should display the next object details from array `data` and continue the same process in same way till it reaches the end of he object .

For current scenario i inserted three object but in real-time it can be length of any object length can be any inside of array

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const data = [
  {
    Name: "COOL",
    title: "SuperCOOL",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    Name: "DEMON",
    title: "SuperDEMON",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    Name: "SPIDER",
    title: "SuperSPIDER",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    Name: "SUPER",
    title: "SuperSUPER",
    id: 4
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [modalShowing, setModalShowing] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button onClick={() => setModalShowing(true)}>Show</Button>
      <Modal
        show={modalShowing}
        onHide={() => setModalShowing(false)}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            <p>Details</p>
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div>hi</div>
          <Button>Next</Button>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the current index and show the proper information from your `data` object.

I did a live demo for you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hodgkin-1y4hi?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const data = [
  {
    Name: "COOL",
    title: "SuperCOOL",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    Name: "DEMON",
    title: "SuperDEMON",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    Name: "SPIDER",
    title: "SuperSPIDER",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    Name: "SUPER",
    title: "SuperSUPER",
    id: 4
  }
];
export default function App() {
  const [modalShowing, setModalShowing] = React.useState(false);
  const [stepIndex, setSteIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const navigateToNext = () => {
    if (stepIndex >= data.length - 1) return;
    setSteIndex(prevState => prevState + 1);
  };
const navigateBack = () => {
    if (stepIndex === 0) return;
    setSteIndex(prevState => prevState - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button onClick={() => setModalShowing(true)}>Show</Button>
      <Modal
        show={modalShowing}
        onHide={() => setModalShowing(false)}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            <p>Details</p>
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <span>{data[stepIndex].title}</span>
        </Modal.Body>
       <Modal.Footer>
          {stepIndex > 0 && 
<Button onClick={navigateBack}>Previous</Button>}
          {stepIndex >= data.length - 1 ? (
            <Button onClick={() => setModalShowing(false)}>Exit</Button>
          ) : (
            <Button onClick={navigateToNext}>Next</Button>
          )}
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to solve this  when it reach end of object the next button to change to Exit Button?

Comment: Hi @Deivison Sporteman can you do tell how can i add Previous Button too, once its move to next

Comment: almost same logic of next button, I did update the example with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain an index and increase that on clicking
here is a live demo https://codesandbox.io/live/WAAKE

```
   import React from "react";
   import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

   import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

   const data = [
   {
     Name: "COOL",
     title: "SuperCOOL",
     id: 1
   },
   {
    Name: "DEMON",
    title: "SuperDEMON",
    id: 2
   },
   {
    Name: "SPIDER",
    title: "SuperSPIDER",
    id: 3
   },
   {
    Name: "SUPER",
    title: "SuperSUPER",
    id: 4
   }
  ];

  export default function App() {
 const [modalShowing, setModalShowing] = React.useState(false);
 const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);


 changeIndex =()=>{
 setIndex(index+1)
 }

return (
<div className="App">
  <Button onClick={() => setModalShowing(true)}>Show</Button>
  <Modal
    show={modalShowing}
    onHide={() => setModalShowing(false)}
    size="lg"
    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
    centered
  >
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
        <p>Details</p>
      </Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      {index!==4&&(
        <>
      <div>{data[index].Name}</div>
      <Button onClick={this.changeIndex}>Next</Button>
      </>)}
      {index===4&&(
      <Button >Exit</Button>)}
      
    </Modal.Body>
  </Modal>
</div>
);
}
```